# Angularjs display value with html

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angularjs

How to display Html from `value`? Like @Html.Raw() in ASP.NET. Because in current example i get only text with tags.

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('Demo', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.value = '<p>List</p><ul><li>Test 1</li><li>Test 2</li><li>Test 3</li><li>Test 4</li></ul>'
});
```

**view**:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    {{value}}
</div>
```

Comment: You can use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use

```
<div ng-bind-html="value"></div>
```

instead of

```
{{value}}
```

you have to use `$sce` provider to process your code to get a safe context.

```
$scope.value= $sce.trustAsHtml("yourHtmlCode");
```

Comment: <span ng-bind="value"></span> this work for me.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the ng-bind-html directive, you can read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-bind-html="{value}">
```